# Logging to a new file for a continues running script

Tags: linux, logs, scripting, compression

I have a script providing login continuously( like 2-3 pages in a second). I was using below one liner.

`sh myscript.sh > /home/user/mylog`

I am running another script to zip this file when it reaches 100MB and create new file.

`gzip /home/user/mylog;touch /home/user/mylog`

But I think I am losing some logs in the time between `gzip` and `touch` commands.Can somebody suggest a best practice NOT to lose any logs?

Comment: In logrotate, there is an option called copytruncate.  There are also multiple options around compression.  You would want to read up on those.

Comment: The man page says::
`Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating  it,
              so some logging data might be lost.`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/189477/rotate-logs-of-a-dumb-non-interactive-application/189880#189880

Answer (score 0):

Rather than zip the file as its being written to, move it out of the way then zip the static file...

mv /home/user/mylog /home/user/mylog.0; gzip /home/user/mylog.0

You shouldn't need the touch, as the script runs, if the log file disappears, it should create it on its own.

Here is a test:
Run this script...
`for (( ; ; )); do echo "123" >> test.log; sleep 1; done`

then move the file to a new name....
`mv test.log test.log.0`

The new test.log is created automatically, assuming the script is still running.

Try this in the While loop. It worked when I tested it.

```
while true;do
  exec 3>&1 1>>time.logger 2>&1
  date;
  #other stuff...
done
```

Comment: I am not sure that will work, didn't work for me. After moving the file, when I tried to `head` the file, it show: 
`head: cannot open '/home/user/mylog' for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: you cannot do a "head" on a file that doesn't exist, but the output stream from your script will create the new log file for you. I updated my original answer with an example.

Comment: Okay. `for` loop is working, but I was trying with while loop and not working. Any Idea why?

`giv@8:~$ cat time-loop 
while true;do date;done
giv@8:~$ cat time-loop 
while true;do date;done
giv@8:~$ sh time-loop >> time.logger &
[2] 26536
giv@8:~$ head -1 time.logger 
Fri Dec  9 18:44:06 IST 2016
giv@8:~$ mv time.logger time.logger.0
giv@8:~$ head -1 time.logger 
head: cannot open 'time.logger' for reading: No such file or directory
giv@8:~$ ps aux | grep time-loop| grep -v grep
giv   26536 12.5  0.0   4508  1708 pts/11   S    18:44   0:03 sh time-loop`

Comment: what is the significance of doing the 'head -1 time.logger' immediately after moving the log? Can't you just get rid of it? can you post your script in its entirety?

Comment: I tried your `for` loop example and it works. My issue is with the `while` loop. The loop I am trying now is `while true;do date;done`. I put it in a file and run like `sh time-loop >> time.logger &`. But once I move the `time.logger`, it is not creating again. I am using `head` just to check whether the file is created or not, anyway the file is NOT creating again. Please try for yourself.

Comment: and I believe it is not about `loop`. If I give the logging inside the script it works like you said even after moving it. In my way, it is not creating new file.

Comment: I have confirmed your issue. Any reason you can't change your while loop to `while true;do date >> test.log ;done` I tested that and it works.

Comment: This is not the actual script. It includes many other things and this `while` loop. I am testing the logging part as it is very important for us. Just want to know how to get the complete logs without losing anything.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: My script is doing other things apart from while loop. The sript will be like `for loop;do something; do someotherthing; while loop; do anotherthing;if....fi;....`. So I want to set the logging outside.